# Can't get simple Python threading to work

Tags: python, multithreading

I am new to threading (though not a beginner in Python) and I am having trouble making a thread work. I have the following simpl(est) program, but I cannot seem to get the function do_something() called. I must be doing something very basic wrong. Can anyone tell me what? Thanks a ton!

```
import threading

def do_something():
    print 'Function called...'

t = threading.Thread(target=do_something)
```

---

Of course, I had unwittingly previously deleted the t.start() instruction (Damn you Synaptic touchpad!!!!!!)

Answer (score 5):

You should start the thread:

```
import threading

def do_something():
    print 'Function called...'

t = threading.Thread(target=do_something)
t.start() # you forgot this line
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to start your thread:

```
t.start()
```